# I am trying to filter a dataset by its unique rows, and the unique row i want chosen is the one with the earliest survey date

Tags: r, date, unique

I have a dataset of 200 participants. each participant has 25 rows of data. I want to create a new dataset with only one row per participant, and I want that row selected to be the one that was completed first. Here is some pseudocode for what i want to do

```
newdataset <- distinct(mydataframe, ID, .keepall = True, where row selected = min(surveydate))

what my data looks like now:
  ID   SurveyDate ...Weekly test score cols...
  1     Jan 1 2019        8
  1     Jan 7 2019        19
  1     Jan 14 2019
.
.
.
22 more rows for participant 1
.
.
.
2      April 29 2019       16
2      May 6 2019          6
2      May 13 2019         4
.
.
.
22 more rows for participant 2
.
.
.
etc. (i.e. 25 rows per participant, there are 200 participants)
```

This is my desired output
desired output

```
ID   Date          .....Weekly test score cols......
1     Jan 1 2019           8
2     April 29 2019        16
.
.
.
should be 200 rows
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Try : `mydataframe %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(which.min(surveydate))`

Answer (score 0):

First convert `SurveyDate` to date class and use `which.min` to select the row with minimum `SurveyDate` value.

```
library(dplyr)

mydataframe %>%
  mutate(SurveyDate = as.Date(SurveyDate, '%b %d %Y')) %>%
  #You can also use lubridate::mdy to convert to date
  #mutate(SurveyDate = lubridate::mdy(SurveyDate)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.min(SurveyDate)) -> result

result
```